# Can someone provide me with an example how to use a remote transactional queue in Msmq 4.0?

Tags: msmq

I would like to receive messages from a remote transactional queue. In Msmq 4.0, this should be possible, but I can't make it work. Does anybody have an example on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code example is the same as local transactional read. [Look at the MS DTC configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700128(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Indeed, I have just figured it out. Thx.